# How to implement a random image in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

with some help I now have a program that gives me a random order of poker cards.

Now I want my programm to show me images of those cards, in the specific random order.
I've named the folders and images by the ranks and suits, to tell the programm which image to use, but for some reason, it doesn't work.

Here is my HTML and Javascript code:

```js
var deck = [];

function setCards(){
  var suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"];
  var ranks = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"];
  
  suits.forEach(function(suit){
     ranks.forEach(function(rank){
      var card = {};
      card.suit = suit;
      card.rank = rank;
      deck.push(card);
     });
      
    });
}

function newCard(count) {
  var remainingCards = 52 - count;
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * remainingCards);
  var card= deck[index];
  deck.splice(index,1);
  return card;
 }

function dealCards() {
  document.getElementById('hand').innerHTML = '<dt> Deck </dt>';
  setCards();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
  var card = newCard(i);
  document.getElementById('hand').innerHTML += new Image(335, 442);

  card.src = '/Game/'card.rank'/'card.suit'.png';
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="CardGame.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CardGame.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="dealCards()">Shuffle Deck</button>
    <hr/> 
    <img id = "hand">
</body>
</html>
```

My folders have exactly the names of the suits and the images of the ranks.
For you, it is probably obvious what is  wrong with my code, but I can't see it.
If you got the mistake, could you please tell me?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense: `document.getElementById('hand').innerHTML += new Image(335, 442);` Even if it was possible to serialize the `Image` instance to HTML, you cannot have an image inside another image. It looks like the element with ID `hand` should really be a `div`, not an `img`.

Comment: `bild.src = '/Game/'card.rank'/'card.suit'.png';`
 You reference a `bild` in this line that's not used anywhere else - what is that? Also, you need to concatenate strings and variables using a plus sign.

Comment: @Jon you're right, I didn't pay enough attention there! That should be "card.src"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with your code. Firstly you need to concat the image src string properly `'/Game/' + card.rank + '/' + card.suit + '.png';` you also have to insert the image correctly using `appendChild()`

Take a look at this working example:

```js
var deck = [];

function setCards(){
  var suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"];
  var ranks = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"];
  
  suits.forEach(function(suit){
     ranks.forEach(function(rank){
      var card = {};
      card.suit = suit;
      card.rank = rank;
      deck.push(card);
     });
      
    });
}

function newCard(count) {
  var remainingCards = 52 - count;
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * remainingCards);
  var card= deck[index];
  deck.splice(index,1);
  return card;
 }

function dealCards() {
  document.getElementById('hand').innerHTML = '<dt> Deck </dt>';
  setCards();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
  var card = newCard(i);
  var img = new Image(335, 442);
  img.src = '/Game/' + card.rank + '/' + card.suit + '.png';
  img.alt = card.rank + ' of ' + card.suit;
  document.getElementById('hand').appendChild(img);

  }
}
```

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="CardGame.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CardGame.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="dealCards()">Shuffle Deck</button>
    <hr/> 
    <div id = "hand"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey itodd, thanks for your help :) When I use your code, it's a bit strange. The names of the random cards are still there, and below them is exactly enough space for the image of the card, but it's empty. Do I have to change the css file here?

Comment: Run this code on your site where you have then images uploaded. If you do not want to see the image names you can remove the `alt` attribute by removing this line `img.alt = card.rank + ' of ' + card.suit;`

Comment: I don't have a site or so. I'm just trying to learn HTML and Javascript. I use the "Brackets" Ide if you know it, and simply have 4 folders called "Clubs","Diamonds","Hearts" and "Spades" with images called "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", etc. Shouldn't it work that way as well?

Comment: If that is how your images are stored then you structured the image src wrong. It should be `img.src = '/Game/' + card.suit + '/' + card.rank + '.png';`